Saml Logout response is not getting generated
I am trying to implement saml2 using spring-security-saml2-service-provider. I am using version 6.3.3. I only have controllers in my application. I am able to do the login properly. But when I want to logout from IDP that is logout initiated from idp. I see that the logout request is coming to the SP and it is processing fine I don't see any errors in the logs in fact when I debugged I see the Saml2LogoutResponse getting generated at saml2LogoutRequestFilter. but I don't see any logout response going back to the IDP.
This is my security configuration
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    return http.
            csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()).
            authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                    .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/samlLogin")).authenticated()
                    .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/*")).permitAll()
                )
            .saml2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .saml2Metadata(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .saml2Logout(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .securityContext(securityContext -> securityContext.
                      securityContextRepository(new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository())
                )
            .build();
}

    @Bean
public RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository registrationRepository() {
    
    RelyingPartyRegistration registration =RelyingPartyRegistrations.
    fromMetadataLocation("idp.xml").
    registrationId(registrationId)
    .entityId(spEntityID)
    .nameIdFormat("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient")
    .singleLogoutServiceBinding(Saml2MessageBinding.POST)
    .singleLogoutServiceLocation(LogoutServiceLocation)
     .signingX509Credentials(credential -> credential.add(asSigningCredential()))
    .decryptionX509Credentials(decryptioncredential -> decryptioncredential.add(asDecryptionCredential()))
    .build();
    return new InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository(registration);
    
}

This is the log information:
2024-11-08 18:03:45 DEBUG o.a.x.s.utils.DigesterOutputStream - Pre-digested input:
2024-11-08 18:03:45 DEBUG o.a.x.s.utils.DigesterOutputStream - <saml2p:LogoutResponse xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Destination="https:idp.com/idp/samlSLO" ID="LR71aaf86c-46e9-4e74-b713-1df71f15c2da" InResponseTo="_1c7b9b6475e13434fff5c2e8a2286878" IssueInstant="2024-11-08T12:33:45.888Z" Version="2.0"><saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://sp.com:443</saml2:Issuer>saml2p:Status<saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"></saml2p:StatusCode></saml2p:Status></saml2p:LogoutResponse>
2024-11-08 18:03:45 DEBUG o.a.x.s.utils.SignerOutputStream - Canonicalized SignedInfo:
2024-11-08 18:03:45 DEBUG o.a.x.s.utils.SignerOutputStream - <ds:SignedInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"></ds:SignatureMethod>
<ds:Reference URI="#LR71aaf86c-46e9-4e74-b713-1df71f15c2da">
ds:Transforms
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></ds:Transform>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></ds:DigestMethod>
ds:DigestValue2t7PoCNN4cnijQH54VmV62w2eEryZ7BghBblG91uCII=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>


I don't see any logs further there is no clue what happened to the response? why it did not sent from the SP.
But when I change the Saml2MessageBinding.POST to Saml2MessageBinding.GET then the logout response is reaching the IDP. But again the session at SP is not invalidated. I am still able to get the authenticated user details.

Answering here, incase any one else facing the same issue.

The HttpSession was not getting invalidated cause the JSESSIONID was not coming in the logout request due to the SameSite changes happened. So need to configure this.
The Logout response was not being sent cause of the X-Frame-Options: Deny set by the spring security. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/exploits/headers.html#headers-frame-options so cause of this it was not setting the responses in my case.

